# Weird apache logs

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2012

I noticed some weird apache access logs lately (IP addresses redacted)

I have multiple lines like the following:

```
[18/Jan/2015:19:10:18 +0200] "CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "-"
[18/Jan/2015:19:10:18 +0200] "GET http://www. sexlovefree .net/sexforum/forumdisplay.php?fid=11 HTTP/1.1" 302 318 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0)"
```

I see all these requests get a 3xx redirection codes.
Does this mean my server has been acting as a proxy?

If yes, is there any fix I can do for this?

Comment: Hard to tell without configuration information.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me whether those log entries mean your server really serves proxy requests. I doubt it though.

To be sure, please follow the instructions I'm quoting from [the Apache Wiki.](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse) and read the rest of the text you find there.

> ## How can I prevent these requests from accessing the foreign server through my server?
>
> First, if you don't need to run a proxy server, disable mod_proxy by
>   commenting out its `LoadModule` line or setting `ProxyRequests off` in
>   httpd.conf. Remember that disabling ProxyRequests does not prevent you
>   from using a reverse proxy with the `ProxyPass` directive.
>
> If you do need to have Apache act as a proxy server, be sure to secure
>   your server by restricting access with a `<Proxy>` section in
>   httpd.conf.
>
> ## My server is properly configured not to proxy, so why is Apache returning a 200 (Success) status code?
>
> That status code indicates that Apache successfully sent a response to
>   the client, but not necessarily that the response was retrieved from
>   the foreign website.
>
> RFC2616 section 5.1.2 mandates that Apache must accept requests with
>   absolute URLs in the request-URI, even for non-proxy requests. This
>   means that even when proxying is turned off, Apache will accept
>   requests that look like proxy requests. But instead of retrieving the
>   content from the foreign site, Apache will serve the content at the
>   corresponding location on your website. Since the hostname probably
>   doesn't match a name for your site, Apache will look for the content
>   on your default host.
>
> In the above example, since www.yahoo.com is obviously not a valid
>   virtual host on your system, Apache will serve the homepage content
>   from your default (virtual) host. The size of the response (1456 in
>   the above example) can be compared to the size of the corresponding
>   page on your default site to confirm that the response was served
>   locally and no proxying was involved.